# Regression in R on panel data

Tags: r, dataframe, lm

I would like to run a linear regression on panel data. Below my code so far but, I don't understand why is not returning the fit and rsq. Any suggestion?

**Sample code:**

```
for(i in names(df))
{ 
  if(is.numeric(df[3,i]))  ##if row 3 is numeric, the entire column is 
  {       
    fit <- lm(df[3,i] ~ Gender, data=df) #does a regression for each column in my csv file against my independent variable 'etch'
    rsq <- summary(fit)$r.squared
  }
}
```

**Data structure**

[image]

**Sample data:**

```
    df<-structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2), id1 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3), 
    a1 = c(5, 8, 7, 6, 3), a2 = c(1, 4, 3, 10, 5), a3 = c(2, 
    34, 3, 12, 6), a4 = c(9, 2, 3, 12, 7), a5 = c(0, 0, 0, 7, 
    8), a6 = c(7, 7, 0, 0, 9), a7 = c(5, 8, 7, 6, 0), a8 = c(1, 
    4, 3, 10, 3), a9 = c(2, 34, 3, 12, 3), a10 = c(9, 2, 3, 12, 
    3), Gender = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), id1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), a1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), a2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), a3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), a4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), a5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), a6 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), a7 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), a8 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), a9 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), a10 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Gender = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "returning"? Are you expecting the for loop to return some sort of value? Or are you list trying to write data to some unnamed file with `writelines`? And is that a typo? Because there is no base R function named `writelines` (there is a `writeLines` which is different because R names are case-sensitive)

Comment: @MrFlick thanks I removed writeline, but still the summary statistics are not computed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fit a linear regression on each column you can use `lapply`. We use `reformulate` to create a formula object from the column name and use it in `lapply`. R-squared value can be extracted from `summary` of each model.

```
cols <- grep('a\\d+', names(df), value = TRUE)
cols
#[1] "a1"  "a2"  "a3"  "a4"  "a5"  "a6"  "a7"  "a8"  "a9"  "a10"

lapply(cols, function(x) {
  lm(reformulate('Gender', x), df)
}) -> fit

r.squared <- sapply(fit, function(x) summary(x)$r.squared)
```